# How to count data in tree-like structure in SQL, for every node

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, hierarchy

I have a tree like this:
[image]

I have this tree hierarchy in table. One row for every node.
I want to display count of children for every node in the tree.
Result would be:

```
ID COUNT
100 9
129 5
439 3
450 1
501 2
602 1
134 3
133 2
```

Table schema:

```
Table - Organization_structure
orgID
parentID

Table - Organization_detail
RID (PK)
OrganizationID
ParentOrganizationID

data:
orgID parrent ID
602   501
501   439
450   129
439   129
129   100
133   134
134   100

RID OrganizationID ParentOrganizationID
1   100            top
2   129            100
3   439            129
4   450            129
5   501            439
6   602            501
7   134            100
8   133            134
9   133            134
```

Any help how to achieve  this? Best in SQL server.

Comment: Please add your table schema.

Comment: @McNets I addet table schema :)

Comment: What data is in each of those two tables?

Comment: there are two ID=133

Comment: @McNets yes they are two, in addition all of the nodes has it's own PK witch is RID

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit complicated because you should use a recursive query and then I've used a CROSS APPLY join to count records:

I've set up next example, (before you post your data)

```
CREATE TABLE Organization_structure (orgID int, parentID int);

INSERT INTO Organization_structure VALUES
(100, NULL),
(129, 100),
(134, 100),
(439, 129),
(450, 129),
(133, 134),
(133, 134),
(501, 439),
(602, 501);
```

This is my solution:

```
with tree as
(
    select orgId, parentId,0 as tree_order, path = cast('root' as varchar(100)) 
    from   Organization_structure 
    where  parentID is null
    union all
    select os.orgId, os.parentId, 1 + tree_order as tree_order,
           path = cast(tree.path + '/' + right(('000000000' + os.orgId), 10) as varchar(100))
    from   Organization_structure os
    join   tree 
    on     tree.orgId = os.parentId
)
select orgId, tree_order, path, t2.cnt 
from tree
cross apply (select count(*) cnt from tree t1 where t1.path like tree.path + '%') t2
order by tree_order;
```

And this is the result:

> ```
> orgId | tree_order | path                 | cnt
> ----: | ---------: | :------------------- | --:
>   100 |          0 | root                 |   9
>   129 |          1 | root/129             |   5
>   134 |          1 | root/134             |   3
>   133 |          2 | root/134/133         |   2
>   133 |          2 | root/134/133         |   2
>   439 |          2 | root/129/439         |   3
>   450 |          2 | root/129/450         |   1
>   501 |          3 | root/129/439/501     |   2
>   602 |          4 | root/129/439/501/602 |   1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=608597f12b6988040c89b2e9478ca9af)*

Comment: Thanks looks good!
What if I would like to sort by another property, look at this:
[link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e2ca5d4367a3a1aabcf374874de25608) _italic_ **bold** `code`

I added new column 'type' and would like to count only between rows where this property match


I would like to see results like
`450 2 root/129/450 5 5 dusan
450 2 root/129/450 6 6 peter`

Comment: You should add this filter to the cross join too, `select sum(amount) cnt from tree t1 where t1.type = tree.type and t1.path like tree.path + '%'`  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e528b8b57ce52adf2a5a1083289e99e9

Comment: what if the root is not defined in data? I am getting 0 rows result for my data

Comment: What's the first row? I've used: `where  parentID is null`

Comment: I managed to do it. @McNets any idea how to make it run faster? I have a bunch of different trees what I am applying this calculations for.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your data to `hierarchyid`, you could use the `IsDescendantOf` method to get those. There may be a simpler way, but this was my first thought. The first part is just formatting the data for hierarchyid.

The count magic comes where I find all nodes which are descendents of the current node. By grouping on the `orgid` you get the count of all descendents.

```
with data (OrgId, ParentOrgId) as
(
    select 100, null union all
    select 129, 100 union all
    select 134, 100 union all
    select 133, 134 union all
    select 135, 134 union all
    select 439, 129 union all
    select 450, 129 union all
    select 501, 439 union all
    select 602, 501 
), cte as
(
    select 
        sPath = cast(concat('/', OrgId, '/') as varchar(max)),
        Path = hierarchyid::Parse(concat('/', OrgId, '/')),
        PreviousPath = hierarchyid::GetRoot(),
        OrgId,
        ParentOrgId
    from data
    where ParentOrgId is null
    union all
    select 
        sPath = cast(concat(c.sPath, s.OrgId, '/') as varchar(max)),
        Path = hierarchyid::Parse(concat(c.sPath, s.OrgId, '/')),
        PreviousPath = c.Path,
        OrgId = s.OrgId,
        ParentOrgId = s.ParentOrgId
    from cte c
    inner join data s
        on c.OrgId = s.ParentOrgId
)
select a.OrgId, NumChildren = count(1)
from cte a
inner join cte b
    on b.Path.IsDescendantOf(a.Path) = 1
group by a.OrgId
```

You might even be able to just keep a running total inside the CTE checking for descendents while simultaneously constructing the `hierarchyid` path.

Comment: thanks for your answer, what If I have not defined what is root node? Here is defined by  value (100, null)
but I don't have always this value in data.

Comment: I only identified the root node by the absence of a parent, not any explicit value.  As long as your root node is defined similarly, it should just work